# Connect to wifi but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Very strange but both my wifi and cable internet connections suddenly stopped working after 2+ years.  NO major installs or updates.  I'm running 16.04.  I can confirm that both router and wifi are working with other devices.  On my laptop running Ubuntu, I can connect to the wifi successfully, but "no sites can be reached" in my browser.  So debilitating.

Comment: Check if you have a default route with the next hop define as the IP of your box (`ip route`). Confirm the configuration of your DNS (`nslookup 8.8.8.8` and `systemd-resolve --status`).

Comment: Thanks.  Ran commands.  Details below.  systemd-resolve gave me error.

Comment: mike@Ubuntu2:-$: ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s25  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s25  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.68  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.112  metric 600 

mike@Ubuntu2:~$ nslookup 8.8.8.8
Server:  162.242.211.137
Address: 162.242.211.137#53

*** Can't find 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.: No answer

mike@Ubuntu2:~$ systemd-resolve --status
systemd-resolve: unrecognized option '--status

Comment: Your resolution seems to not working correctly. Try the command  `sudo dhclient [INTERFACE_NAME] -v`

Comment: What is the exact result of: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ping to 8.8.8.8 works.  What is the [INTERFACE_NAME]?  Sorry bit new to the networking part of ubutnu.

Comment: Found INTERFACE NAME.  Details below.

mike@Ubuntu2:~$ sudo dhclient wlp3s0 -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/28:b2:bd:06:52:4d
Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/28:b2:bd:06:52:4d
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.112 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1d573037)
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.112 from 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.1.112 -- renewal in 32861 seconds.

Comment: @Markdd, it's SOP here to click on https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054167/edit and update your original query with new information when you find more facts. That helps everyone grasp what's going on.

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` followed by: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  Suggestions pointed me down a fruitful path.  Figured out what was happening.  My VPN provider had changed - or more correctly - retired the DNS IP addresses in by resolv.conf file.  Once I updated to the new items I was good.